# How to print 80-bit double extended precision floating point number in assembly x8086?

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm working on a homework assignment, and want to print a 80-bit double extended precision number via printf. The number is calculated by some scaling function and using gdb i see it calculates the right number. I point to the block of 10 bytes using a some pointer named var1 defined in section bss as: var1: rest 1
then var1 points to a block of 10 bytes in the memory.

So far i tried to push the 10 bytes into the stack and then printing the number with format %f or %lf, both failed to print the number, also i noticed using qword and pushing 4 bytes twice into the stack (part of the number worked well), but i'm required using tword definition.

---

```
scale_number:
  push ebp                  ;; Pushing Base pointer (contains address of current activation frame
                            ;; which is actually the return address of the caller) to the stack

  mov ebp, esp              ;; Overrides ebp value to Stack pointer's value which contains the
                            ;; address of last used dword in the stack.

  pushad                    ;; Push all significant registers (8 general purpose registers)
                            ;; onto the stack (backup registers values)

  mov ebx, [ebp + 12]       ;; Upper bound
  sub dword ebx, [ebp + 8]  ;; Substruct ebx with the Lower bound
  mov ecx, [ebp + 16]       ;; get the pointer of the result contianer

  finit

  mov eax, dword [seed]
  mul ebx
  push eax
  fild dword [esp]
  add esp, 4
  push 0x0000FFFF
  fidiv dword [esp]
  add esp, 4
  fiadd dword [ebp + 8]
  fstp tword [ecx]

  ffree

  popad
  return_from_function ; macro for quiting the function
```

right now ecx points to var1

the rest of the code:

---

```
  push dword var1
  push 100
  push 40

  call scale_number

  ;; Floating point tester TWORD
  sub esp, 10
  mov ebx, 0
  .loop4:
    mov eax, [var1 + ebx]
    mov [esp + ebx], eax
    inc ebx
    cmp ebx, 10
    jne .loop4

  push format_fp ;; using "%f" , 10, 0 as the format_fp
  call printf
  add esp, 14

  jmp exit
```

the output i have is -0.000000, but my expected output is 80. something..

Comment: `sub esp, 10` is very bad. You should always maintain at least 4 byte alignment. Probably doesn't have anything to do with your issue just saying. Try `%Lf` with capital `L` for a 80 bit value. Also consult your libc manual.

Comment: it works, printing 80.466926. Can you give further explanation for ```sub esp, 10``` is very bad. You should always maintain at least 4 byte alignment

Comment: Stack pointer must be a multiple of 4 (under certain calling conventions, even 16). 10 is not a multiple of 4 so assuming stack pointer is aligned before that, it will be misaligned after. Allocate 12 bytes instead, even though you only need 10. In case of 16 byte alignment requirement you will have to consider your whole function.

Comment: You can use `fbstp` for a quick and dirty conversion routine.